Ubuntu 24.04 Second display not showing connected as "Unkown display"
I have just install ubuntu 24.04 and everything is fine except the second display showing as "Unknown display" on displays menu. The exact same display working without any issue with ubuntu 22.04 but in another pc.

The result of the command xrandr -q
I tried switching Xorg from Wayland but did not work.
Here is result of the command xrandr -q

It shows second display as Connected but "None-1-1"
I have also Nvidia videocard installed with some drivers. No idea how does it work. If there any details I can provide. I can add it here.

I think this is the bug reported at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/2060268
